# Swapping License Keys in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macbook, virtual-machine, boot-camp, parallels

I have a Macbook Pro that dual boots with a retail version of Windows 7. I recently purchased Parallels 6, hoping that I could have the best of both worlds. Dual Boot for performance, VM for reference. It should have occurred to me beforehand, hoping that Parallels would mimic the Boot Camp environment, but I had to reactivate my copy of Windows running as a VM.

Slightly upset with Parallels lack of fore warning, I understand the licensing implications of running Windows 7 in two different environments.

I have an MSDN subscription, which entitles me to use Windows 7 Enterprise, which I believe can cope with being installed on up to four different environments.

1. Would Windows 7 Enterprise require reactivation every time I switched between Boot Camp and Parallels?
2. If not, I've spent a good deal of time getting my Windows 7 installation the way I want it. Is it possible to tell the existing installation (Ultimate Retail) that it is now Enterprise?

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) At some point possibly, usually if it is installed on the same hardware it will activate with no issues, but you can call MS to get it activated again if does not.

for W7  1-888-725-1047  USA

2.) No, once installed you cannot switch versions. EDIT (You can if you use the Anytime Upgrade from Microsoft)

.

Comment: I thought changing the licence key changed the edition? As all discs can install all windows 7 versions now?

Comment: No. once it is installed you cannot change the version. Yes some Install discs can install any version if you have the correct key, but once you select your edition during installation setup it cannot be changed.

Comment: Seems like it might have been a false alarm. I've not been asked to reactivate either configuration, beyond the initial activations of both.